# Stata Date-- type mismatch

Tags: stata

The Stata file I am using has a `Date` column. I am not sure whether the 
data is already in Stata data format. If not, please provide some guideline.

As a neophyte, I tried the following code

```
. generate date2 = date(Date,"DMY")
type mismatch
```

The `Date` column entries look like the following

```
31jan1995
28feb1995
31mar1995
30apr1995
...
```

More info: `Type=long Format=%d`

Comment: I think you mean "date format" not "data format".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` variable (not column in Stata terms) is already a numeric variable formatted appropriately as a daily date.

So, the `date()` function complains because it expects a string variable name or string expression as first argument.

The only other noteworthy detail is that `%d` is no longer documented routinely as a daily date display format; in recent Stata versions, `%td` is the documented equivalent.